# How to not to feel igry for children's behavior?

Tags: parents, emotional-well-being

Examples:

- Approaching strangers in public places and talk to them also if they show hints they do not want to
- Going to nursery school in pyjama

This makes parents feeling so much igry and full of wrath and that all the focus is spent not to go nuts (instead of developing positive corrective approaches).

Ideas to make it better?

Comment: This is pretty broad and pretty vague. Do you want your child to stop or do you want to stop going nuts? Why? What have you tried? Why didn't it help? Etc. If you can add details and be specific in your question, please edit your post and flag for moderator intervention. Thanks.

Comment: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=igry

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok J Doe. Assuming you basically meant to say "my child makes me mad. what do I do?" Let's break some things down here:

First of all, who cares? You were a kid once. You might have had a favorite shirt. Maybe you wanted to wear it all the time. Is that a reason for your parents to get mad at you? Going to nursery school in pajamas - trust me they won't be phased by this unless they specifically forbid it. If that's the case, how about you redefine what pajamas are to your kid?

Talking to strangers - welllllll... Going to have to say that's not a bad thing either when you factor in the fact that you mentioned nursery school. At that age kids who express social interest are doing great. Would you worry if your kid refused to interact with society at all?

I get the idea this feels a little like a first time parent panic question. I know what it feels like to be trapped by the crushing horror of obligation, but if you can just say "screw it" to like everything that's making you upset you might realize there's nothing to it. Enjoy your kids. Delight in the grand comedy that they want to go to school in pajamas and like talking to people. Laugh at it. So what if they don't like carrots? So what if they prefer sleeping with no pillow? So what about so many things?

You will be so much more sane if you just see them as someone living their lives. They'll like what they like, do what they do, and if you don't lose yourself in anger they will love you no matter what you decide to go to work in or who you talk to in society. Just don't spend these years mad. You'll hate yourself for it later.